# Bind a port to a network interface

Tags: interface

Is it possible to bind an arbitrary port, say 1337, to a specific NIC?  I have 2 NICs, one configured for IPv4, the other for IPv6.  I want to ensure that whenever port 1337 is used, it goes through the IPv6 interface.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you can do that using iptables.  A rule in IP table should do it, but I think that the NIC in question has to have a IP assigned to it.  Try this, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
iptables -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport xxxx -i eth1
```

Replace xxxx with the port number.  For more info on iptables see the [Manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/8/iptables)

Comment: It looks like that command would work for the IPv4 interface, but it would need to specify the table like this:  

`iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 10337 -i eth1`
  
I need a solution that works for IPv6, which doesn't have a nat table.

Answer (score 0):

You usually bind a service (that uses a certain port) to an address. So when you bind your service to the IPv6 address you should be set.